# Create a subset of a dictionary, sorting the original dictionary by a list of values.

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, genetics

I'm creating a dictionary (first block of code) and would like to be able to filter out the keys I don't need according to their values, then output this to a CSV.

The values I'd like to match are stored in a list, generated below in the second block of code.

All are strings, no integers.

Here is my code so far:

```
#new_dict = raw_input("Enter Dictionary Name")
#source: http://bit.ly/1iOS0e3
import csv
new_dict = {}
with open(raw_input("Enter csv file (including path)"), 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    if row[0] in new_dict:
      new_dict[row[0]].append(row[1:])
    else:
      new_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]
print new_dict
```

And the list:

```
#modified from: http://bit.ly/1iOS7Gu
import pandas
colnames = ['Date Added to Catalog',    'PUBMEDID', 'First Author', 'Date', 'Journal',  'Link', 'Study',    'DT',   'Initial Sample Size',  'Replication Sample Size',  'Region',   'Chr_id',   'Chr_pos',  'Reported Gene(s)', 'Mapped_gene',  'p-Value',  'Pvalue_mlog',  'p-Value (text)',   'OR or beta',   '95% CI (text)',    'Platform [SNPs passing QC]',   'CNV']
data = pandas.read_csv('C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\gwascatalog.csv', names=colnames)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit unclear on your question - is the idea to take values from `data`, and if the key in `new_dict` is not in a particular column then remove that dictionary item?  Also, your current code stores a list of cell values without separating out by row - is this what you intend?

Comment: @will-hart Yeah that's what I'd like to do.

No, I was intending to separate by row. Perhaps you could help with that too, if you can see a solution tot he original question?

Answer (score 1):

To limit which rows are added to the dictionary you could create a `set` called `filter` which contains the keys that you want to keep.  This could be obtained from your pandas `DataFrame`, for example assuming you wanted to use the `Journal` CSV field as a key:

```
filter = set(data.Journal.values)
```

You could then modify your `for` loop to check whether we should store the row from the CSV file.  This could look like the following:

```
for row in reader:
    if row[0] in filter:
        if row[0] in new_dict:
            new_dict[row[0]].append(row[1:])
        else:
            new_dict[row[0]] = [row[1:]]
```

---

As per your comment, if you want to separate the records by row you need to change the line

```
new_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

to:

```
new_dict[row[0]] = [row[1:]]
```

In the first case for `row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`:

```
my_list = row[1:]
# my_list = [2, 3, 4, 5]
my_list.append(row[1:])
# my_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Whilst in the second case:

```
my_list = [row[1:]]
# my_list = [[2, 3, 4, 5]]
my_list.append(row[1:])
# my_list = [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```